# Can't access environment variables from Visual Studio Code on Mac with Python

Tags: visual-studio-code, environment-variables

first off all I'm using oh-my-zsh as bash.
I've added my API-Key to the .zshrc file as:

`export MYKEY=xxxaldjlsdfjxxxx`

Run source on the .zshrc. When I access this environment variable from the terminal with:

```
python3
>>> import os
>>> mykey = os.environ.get('MYKEY')
>>> print(mykey)
```

and this prints me the value of the key.
Now I'm writing a python script with Visual Studio Code from where I want to access the key. The workspace of the project is located at /Users/myname/Documents/Projectname

If I now run the same code as in terminal:

```
import os
mykey = os.environ.get('MYKEY')
print(mykey)
```

I get a 'None' as output.

Comment: As far as I can tell, this is specifically a problem with the IDE, not with either Python, your shell or your operating system.

Comment: Finally I found the solution, I've to set the environment var inside the .zprofile because the python path is also set inside this file.